# Add a second function to existing jQuery 'On Input' to update element value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have an existing jQuery function that calculates the product of two input fields as they are filled out (before the form is submitted).

I need help expanding this function, or otherwise adding to it, so that each time it does its current calc, it also updates certain  element values with content from other input fields on the page.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $total = $('#total'),
        $value = $('.value');
    $value.on('input', function(e) {
        var total = 1;
        $value.each(function(index, elem) {
            if(!Number.isNaN(parseFloat(this.value)))
                total = total * parseFloat(this.value);
        });
        $total.val(total);
    });
});
```

The end requirement is that the person filling the form sees the total (product of two fields) change as they type, AND they also see the information from their form populate a terms and conditions statement.

Here's a simplified version of my form.

```
<input type="text" size="5" id="value1" name="value1" class="value" />
<input type="text" size="5" id="value2" name="value2" class="value" />

<input type="text" size="5" id="total" readonly="readonly" class="bckground" name="total" />

<h5>First</h5>
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="Enter First Name" size="20" />

<h5>Last</h5>
<input type="text" name="lastname" value="Enter Last Name" size="20" />

<br><br>
I <span id="pledgefirstname">--</span> <span id="pledgelastname">--</span> pledge to donate...
```

Note the two functions really have nothing to do with each other than the fact that they dynamically update information so that the user can see the result of what they are filling out in real time.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QC6GV/8/)

Desired outcome `I Joe Bloggs pledge to donate...` populates dynamically as user fills out their name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I add another answer for this last part.

There were some errors in your code.

For starters, You weren't adding the control `$food` to the jQuery object to which the event listener is attached:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $total = $('#total'),
        $value = $('.value');
        $firstName = $('#firstname');
        $lastName = $('#lastname');
        $food = $('#food');
    $value.add($firstName).add($lastName).add($food).on('change input', function(e) {
        var total = 1;
        $value.each(function(index, elem) {
            if(!Number.isNaN(parseFloat(this.value)))
                total = total * parseFloat(this.value);
        });
        $total.val(total);

        $('#pledgefirstname').text($firstName.val());
        $('#pledgelastname').text($lastName.val());
        $('#pledgefood').text($food.val());
    });
});
```

Besides, your HTML was missing the `value` attributes for the `select`. And there was a typo in the `id` of the `<span>` that contains the food value (it was *pledgefood>*):

```
<h4>Shopping</h4>
<select type="text" id="food" name="food" >
  <option value="Milk">Milk</option>
  <option value="Coffee">Coffee</option>
  <option value="Tea">Tea</option>
</select>

<br><br>
I <span id="pledgefirstname">--</span> <span id="pledgelastname">--</span> pledge to donate <span id="pledgefood">--</span>.
```

New [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QC6GV/23/).

Comment: So do I have to add a listener for each field that I add? Or is there a way to listen globally?

Comment: You can listen globally with this: `$(':input').on(...)`.

Comment: Nice. That's what I need. You have been very helpful and I appreciate that a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/QC6GV/9/) it is a working example.

I just added a second function for the two last inputs. Besides, I've changed the initial value of those inputs and istead used the `placeholder` attribute, which works better and is intended for its use a label that you don't have to erase when you type.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $total = $('#total'),
        $value = $('.value');
        $firstName = $('#firstname');
        $lastName = $('#lastname');
    $value.add($firstName).add($lastName).on('input', function(e) {
        var total = 1;
        $value.each(function(index, elem) {
            if(!Number.isNaN(parseFloat(this.value)))
                total = total * parseFloat(this.value);
        });
        $total.val(total);

        $('#pledgefirstname').text($firstName.val());
        $('#pledgelastname').text($lastName.val());
    });
});
```

Comment: So fast I can't accept the answer:) Thank you so much. It's perfect. And thanks for the tip about the form.

Comment: Don't worry. Accept it when you can.

Comment: I have been testing this and it seems the second function only updates the values when data is typed into the firsname or lastname fields. Is it possible to run these functions every time ANY fields in the form change? e.g. also when I select an item from a drop down list.

Comment: OK thanks, is there a bracket missing? It's not working in the js fiddle.

Comment: Sorry I mean in my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QC6GV/17/). Update to the drop down list does not update jQuery

Comment: It works for me. I have just tested it. What error are you getting?

Comment: When selecting food from drop down, text at the bottom does not update.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49695/discussion-between-square-eyes-and-oscar-paz)